# 5 столбцов ссылаются на 1 внешний ключ

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Есть таблица

```
Чек
ИД 1й поломки
ИД 2й поломки
ИД 3й поломки
ИД 4й поломки
ИД 5й поломки
```

Соответственно 5 полей для имен мастеров, которые чинили и 5 полей стоимости ремонта, но это не важно

И есть таблица

```
Поломки
ИД поломки
Название поломки
Способы ремонта
```

Нужно, чтобы при выводе чека вместо ИД выводилось название соответствующей поломки, но проблема в том, что если в чеке указан перечень разных поломок, то ничего не выводит, а вот если один и тот же ИД продублировать 5 раз, то всё норм. Как сделать так, чтобы всякий раз подставлялось соответствующее имя?

SqlDataSource генерирует такой запрос

```
SELECT checks.checkID, breakdowns.breakname AS breakname1, breakdowns.breakname AS breakname2...
FROM checks INNER JOIN breakdowns
ON checks.breakdownID1 = breakdowns.breakdownID AND checks.breakdownID2 = breakdowns.breakdownID...
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно 5 раз соединить чек с таблицей поломок.

```
SELECT checks.checkID, 
       bd1.breakname AS breakname1, 
       bd2.breakname AS breakname2
       ...
  FROM checks 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN breakdowns bd1
       ON checks.breakdownID1 = bd1.breakdownID 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN breakdowns bd2
       ON checks.breakdownID2 = bd2.breakdownID 
       ...
```

На верность синтаксису именно MS-SQL Server не проверял.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!:)

Comment: Пометьте ответ как верный, если он подходит, пожалуйста.